# Slow Performance of AJAX Submitted Webform

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I am creating a poll that website visitors can then vote. I use a hosted CMS (Business Catalyst) so I have to do a lot of this with javascript.

I have the poll working but when I click submit it is taking around 15 to 20 seconds for the poll to submit. I really need to improve this performance but unsure how to do so.

Below is the script I am using. I did not write this but followed some examples for getting it to work. I am using Business Catalyst's Web Apps to create the poll.

Here is how it works. There is a form on a page that looks like this:

```
<form id="pollAnswers12003343">
    <div class="answers">
            <input id="a1" type="radio" name="radioChoice" value="CAT_Custom_2"> Answer 1<br>
            <input id="a2" type="radio" name="radioChoice" value="CAT_Custom_4"> Answer 2<br>
            <input id="a3" type="radio" name="radioChoice" value="CAT_Custom_6"> Answer 3<br>
    </div>
<button class="button brand vote-btn12003343" type="submit" disabled>Vote</button>
<div class="hide vote-loader12003343">Your vote is submitting, please wait while we tally the votes. <i class="ub ub-refresh ub-spin"></i></div>
</form>
```

The script sees which option the user sees and adds a 1 to the total votes. We then take the information and submit it to the system.

Because we are using web apps, BC required the user to be logged in. Since we do not want to require a user to be logged in to vote, we log in an anonymous user, unless they are already logged in. Take the data, submit the data, logout the anonymous user (we do not log out a logged in user) and reload the page.

Any code in `{{ }}` is rendered on the server. For example `{{itemid}}` would render `123456`, the ID of that web app item.

Here is the code being used.

```
var Engine = {

ui : {

pollSubmit : function(){

if($("#pollAnswers{{itemid}}").size() === 0){return;}

var $form = $("#pollAnswers{{itemid}}"), // ID of Poll
    $radioOptions = $form.find("input[type='radio']"),
    $webAppItemName = "{{name}}", //{{name}} is a system tag that will render the name of the poll
    $formButton = $form.find("button"),

    bcField_1 = "CAT_Custom_2",
    answer_1 = parseInt({{this.['Answer 1 Votes']}}),

    bcField_2 = "CAT_Custom_4",
    answer_2 = parseInt({{this.['Answer 2 Votes']}}),   

    bcField_3 = "CAT_Custom_6",
    answer_3 = parseInt({{this.['Answer 3 Votes']}}),

    $formSubmitData = "",
    preElem;

    $radioOptions.on( "change", function() {
        $formButton.removeAttr("disabled"); 
    });

    $formButton.on( "click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var chosenField = $radioOptions.filter(':checked').val();

          if(chosenField == bcField_1){
              answer_1 = answer_1 + 1;
              $formSubmitData = {
                ItemName: $webAppItemName,

                CAT_Custom_1: "{{this.['Answer 1']}}",
                CAT_Custom_2: answer_1,

                CAT_Custom_3: "{{this.['Answer 2']}}",
                CAT_Custom_4: answer_2,

                CAT_Custom_5: "{{this.['Answer 3']}}",
                CAT_Custom_6: answer_3,

                CAT_Custom_21: "{{this.['Suggested by']}}"
              };
          }

          if(chosenField == bcField_2){
              answer_2 = answer_2 + 1;
              $formSubmitData = {
                ItemName: $webAppItemName,

                CAT_Custom_1: "{{this.['Answer 1']}}",
                CAT_Custom_2: answer_1,

                CAT_Custom_3: "{{this.['Answer 2']}}",
                CAT_Custom_4: answer_2,

                CAT_Custom_5: "{{this.['Answer 3']}}",
                CAT_Custom_6: answer_3,

                CAT_Custom_21: "{{this.['Suggested by']}}"
              };
          }


          if(chosenField == bcField_3){
              answer_3 = answer_3 + 1;
              $formSubmitData = {
                ItemName: $webAppItemName,

                CAT_Custom_1: "{{this.['Answer 1']}}",
                CAT_Custom_2: answer_1,

                CAT_Custom_3: "{{this.['Answer 2']}}",
                CAT_Custom_4: answer_2,

                CAT_Custom_5: "{{this.['Answer 3']}}",
                CAT_Custom_6: answer_3,

                CAT_Custom_21: "{{this.['Suggested by']}}"
              };
          }

          prepForm($formSubmitData);

    });


    function prepForm(formSubmitData){

            //Slides up the vote button and slides down a spinner.
            $( ".vote-btn{{itemid}}" ).slideUp();
            $( ".vote-loader{{itemid}}" ).slideDown();

            //Sets a cookie to let us know they have voted.
            Cookies.set('vote{{itemid}}', '1');

            //Log user in (if already logged in then we run fireForm(formSubmitData); instead)
            logAnonUserIn(formSubmitData); 

    } 

    //User must be logged in to submit a web app. To bypass this, we login an anonymous  user.
    //If user is logged in to the site, this function is not loaded by the system and the next function is ran.
    function logAnonUserIn(formSubmitData){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=-1&Username=anon&Password=anon',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function(){},
        success: function(){},
        complete: function(){
         fireForm(formSubmitData);
        }
      });
    }

    //This is the function that takes the above data and submits it to the CMS.
    function fireForm(formSubmitData){

      var url = "/CustomContentProcess.aspx?A=EditSave&CCID=30980&OID={{itemid}}&OTYPE=35";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: formSubmitData,
            async: true,
            success: function() {},
            error: function() {},
            complete: function(){
                logOutUser(); 
            }
        });
    }

    //Once the form is submitted, we want to logout the user if they are logged in anonymously.
    //If user is logged in with their account, then we reload the page and do not log them out.
    function logOutUser(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/LogOutProcess.aspx',
        complete: function(){
          location.reload(); 
        }
      });
    }

}// pollSubmit
}// end ui
};

Engine.ui.pollSubmit();
```

Any thoughts on how to improve the performance of this script?

**Update**

I added `console.log` to each `complete: function(){}` to follow the status of the submissions. It appears the longest portion is logging in the anonymous user. After that, it appears to move quickly, at least quick enough.

Comment: If you're wondering why it takes a long time to get through `logAnonUserIn`, that's probably because it does three separate `GET` requests.

Comment: @Quill - Anyway to improve that or lower the amount of `GET` request?

Comment: All of your `$.ajax` requests take a while to process and go through, unless you plan to merge them, or something similar, you may not be able to reduce the time.

Answer (score 2):

Having the values in `{{ }}` rendered by the server on your script is a bad idea. What if the server chokes and returns an invalid value? What happens to your script? I suggest that the server creates an object containing all those values, then print that object on the page. This is usually done by creating an object, serializing it to JSON, then print the JSON to the page. Then have your script validate and access that object afterwards.

The next issue is `parseInt`. You have no checks if the value returned by `parseInt` is a number at all. You usually use `isNaN` for that. Also, it's best practice to provide `parseInt` with a base as second argument. This is so that `parseInt` would know how to parse the string. Otherwise, it will treat your string as some other value (octal in some implementations instead of decimal).

I also noticed that you used a cookie to tell whether someone already voted. The problem here is cookies can be deleted. If I go in private mode, or just delete my browser history, I can just vote again. I better option would be to send to the server a bunch of identifying data, a combination of browser name, version, os name, os version, referrer etc. These data are usually present in the HTTP request header, mostly on the useragent string. Then compute a hash for the combination and store it in the server with the vote. Once the user will try to vote again using the setup, it should produce the same hash, you can disregard the vote. It's not foolproof, but the user would need to go through all the hoops just to change the stuff needed by your hash. This is also how ads track you by the way.

Now its down to your AJAX. The problem is you need to fire them in sequence just because you need to login, cast the vote and logout. A better solution would be *to just expose a single public endpoint for anonymous voting*. Because logging in/logging out just makes no sense when the account is pretty much public. You just have to tell your server to record the vote as the public user.